# How to Iteratively remove variables for all possible combinations when concatenating in Python?

Tags: python

I have a local variable that equals other local variables concatenated, how can I iteratively remove each variable so that all combinations are acheived. How can I achieve this without having to redefine `f` each time?

```
if a == b + c + d + e:
    f = b + c + d + e

elif a == b + c + d:
     f = b + c + d 



elif a == b + c:
     f = b + c
```

Comment: From your example, it looks like you could just set `f = a`.

Comment: Perhaps using [`itertools.combinations`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations).

Comment: also I think you mean "==", not "=" cause "==" compares and "=" sets something equal to something else

Comment: I dont understand the question ...

Comment: if `f = a` I would still have to define `a` for every combination.  I would like to set `a` then iterate through every combination a could be with the values, i.e. d+c + e or c+d or b+ e  and so on.

Comment: This sounds a lot like an [XY problem](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node=XY+Problem). Can we stop talking about a's and b's and f's and discuss this concretely? Tell us what started this.

Answer (score 2):

Are you trying to list the [powerset](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#recipes) (minus the empty set)?

```
>>> from itertools import chain, combinations

>>> def powerset(iterable):
        s = list(iterable)
        return chain.from_iterable(combinations(s, r) for r in range(1, len(s)+1))

>>> b, c, d, e = 'bcde'
>>> list(powerset((b, c, d, e)))
[('b',),
 ('c',),
 ('d',),
 ('e',),
 ('b', 'c'),
 ('b', 'd'),
 ('b', 'e'),
 ('c', 'd'),
 ('c', 'e'),
 ('d', 'e'),
 ('b', 'c', 'd'),
 ('b', 'c', 'e'),
 ('b', 'd', 'e'),
 ('c', 'd', 'e'),
 ('b', 'c', 'd', 'e')]
```

You could also join them together, since you said the values were concatenated:

```
>>> map(lambda t: ''.join(t), powerset((b, c, d, e)))
['b',
 'c',
 'd',
 'e',
 'bc',
 'bd',
 'be',
 'cd',
 'ce',
 'de',
 'bcd',
 'bce',
 'bde',
 'cde',
 'bcde']
```

Comment: @wlfynny this is what I am talking about.

Comment: How do you yield the output sets? Print powerset?

Comment: `powerset` returns a [generator](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-generator) object.  `tuple(powerset(args))` or `list(powerset(args))` will convert to a list.  Either `print` or store that.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your example, I'm assuming you just want to chop off one of your variables at a time. If that is the case, this code will do it:

```
# assuming b, c, d, and e are your 'other variables'
strings = [b, c, d, e]

# stores the concatenation of the 4 variables above in f  
f = ''.join(strings)  

# iterate the strings in reverse order
for string in reversed(strings):
   # trim the portion of f at the end that matches the currently iterated string
   f = f[0:f.rfind(string)]
   # perform desired operation on f
```